# Android - java.lang.Security Exception

Tags: android

I have an application with a service that run good in my eclipse, but when i download it to my cellphone or compile with a USB drive, I have this Error :

```
01-06 15:24:22.855: W/dalvikvm(16894): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41ceb700)
01-06 15:24:22.865: E/AndroidRuntime(16894): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-06 15:24:22.865: E/AndroidRuntime(16894): java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=SERVICE_1 (has extras) } without permission not exported from uid 10022
01-06 15:24:22.865: E/AndroidRuntime(16894):    at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceAsUser(ContextImpl.java:1785)
01-06 15:24:22.865: E/AndroidRuntime(16894):    at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1757)
01-06 15:24:22.865: E/AndroidRuntime(16894):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:480)
01-06 15:24:22.865: E/AndroidRuntime(16894):    at com.acantonalocalizacaotop.PaginaInicial$2.onClick(PaginaInicial.java:82)
01-06 15:24:22.865: E/AndroidRuntime(16894):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
01-06 15:24:22.865: E/AndroidRuntime(16894):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
01-06 15:24:22.865: E/AndroidRuntime(16894):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
01-06 15:24:22.865: E/AndroidRuntime(16894):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-06 15:24:22.865: E/AndroidRuntime(16894):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
01-06 15:24:22.865: E/AndroidRuntime(16894):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
01-06 15:24:22.865: E/AndroidRuntime(16894):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-06 15:24:22.865: E/AndroidRuntime(16894):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-06 15:24:22.865: E/AndroidRuntime(16894):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
01-06 15:24:22.865: E/AndroidRuntime(16894):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
01-06 15:24:22.865: E/AndroidRuntime(16894):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my Manifest and my code in the part I call the service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.acantonalocalizacaotop"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" >
</uses-permission>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.acantonalocalizacaotop.PaginaInicial"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Monstros"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_monstros" >
    </activity>

            <service 
        android:name="ServicoLocalizacao" android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="SERVICE_1" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>          
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

</application>



</manifest>
```

And my call code

```
    Intent it = new Intent("SERVICE_1");
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("NomeEquipe", NomeEquipe.getText().toString());
            it.putExtras(bundle);
            startService(it);
```

Can anybody help me please? Y tried to put exported=true as I read in some answers but without success.

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you ensured that you have included all of the necessary permissions for you application?

Comment: Yes my friend, the aplication runs normal in the eclipse. I am only using the internet and the GPS.

Answer (score 0):

Your service simply needs to be exported:

```
<service android:name="ServicoLocalizacao" android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="SERVICE_1" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>          
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```